# Understating use of Salt with AES256 , and sending the data over the network

Tags: servlets, encryption, spring-security, aes, salt

I am trying to encrypt a NSString content and send it to the server.

AES keys, should not be a simple plain text. 
Ex: "Password$5".

A salt should be added to it, so its like randomData + Password$5.

This key will be used for encrypting.

So, to the server I will be sending a JSON like this

```
{
 password:"Encrypted Password with AES256"
}
```

Now, my question is the key is random because the salt is random, so how would i decrypt the AES256 received encrypted string?

Though I know the key (Password$5), but I don't know the salt?

Do I have to send the salt to the server(what would be the best place for it, should it be in the header or in the response itself), is it safe?

```
{
password: "Encrypted Password with AES256",
salt: "Random Hex bytes used"
}
```

Also, any way to handle this with Spring Restful services?

Comment: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/66989/how-does-a-random-salt-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to encrypt data being sent over the wire, you should handle this using a secure connection. This is between the servers, rather than handled by your application code.

If you the data itself should be encrypted, then you want to handle generation of salts, encryption on the server-side.

For passwords, you will want to hash them not encrypt them. There should never be a reason to de-crypt a password. You can always hash the provided password and compare hash values.

Comment: So, does it mean, I have to send the encrypted data as well as the salt

Comment: no just the encrypted data. The server will de-crypt it before your application code gets it, and then you can hash it with your salt and check it

Comment: Which means I can have different salt (of same length , PBKDF2) at server and at client, but the hash result will be same.

Comment: No, not at all.  You need the salt to be the same every time.

Answer (score 2):

Just use https, all data and the query string are encrypted. Add certificate pinning and even MITM attacks are mitigated. Your encryption will be no better.

If you are determined to do your own encryption use [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor). There is little chance that someone not steeped in cryptography will get the security right.

On the server do not save the password, run it through PBKDF2 with a salt and save the salt,iteration count and hashed password.

Comment: Oh, So if send User's password to a server with HTTPS, i don't have to worry about of using AES256. This bring another question in my mind why people still use AES256?

Comment: That is correct. Why wouldn't AES  (Advanced Encryption Standard) still be used, it is the current symmetric encryption standard. https used AES (or another cipher) to encrypt the data.

Comment: There's little chance that RNCryptor will get it right either: http://www.openwall.com/lists/oss-security/2016/01/24/10